# AS3: Trouble passing variables to child function

Tags: function, variables, actionscript, constructor, parent

I recently changed the constructor functions of my display objects to verify they are on stage. However, this has completely broken my ability to pass values to child functions. For example (much code removed for clarity):

Parent:

```
public var var1:uint;
public var var2:uint;
public var childFunction:ChildFunction;

public function createChild():void
{
    childFunction = new ChildFunction( var1, var2 );
    addChild( childFunction );
}
```

Child:

```
public var varA:uint;
public var varB:uint;

public function ChildFunction( varA:uint, varB:uint )
{
    trace( varA, varB );

    if ( stage )
    {
        onAddtoStage();
    }
    else
    {
        addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddtoStage );
    }
}

public function onAddtoStage( e:Event = null ):void
{
    trace( varA, varB );
}
```

In this example, I would get the proper values of `var1` and `var2` in the first trace, but then 0 and 0 in the second. Repeated testing indicates that after leaving the constructor function, the values of varA and varB are completely forgotten as soon as the constructor function is left, even though they're declared as public variables.

I admit there's a lot I don't know about Action Script, but this has me scratching my head. Any help is much appreciated. I know I could just look at the variables in the parent from the child, but that doesn't work for what I need; I need to hand the values down and store them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem of scope.

When you `trace( varA, varB );` in `ChildFunction`, it is using the `varA` and `varB` that are passed in as arguments.

When you `trace( varA, varB );` in `onAddToStage`, it's using the `public var varA:uint;` and `public var varB:uint;` which have never been changed and should therefore be their default of 0.

What I'm assuming you intended to do was to set the `ChildFunction`'s public data in its constructor:

```
public function ChildFunction( varA:uint, varB:uint )
{
    trace( varA, varB );
    this.varA = varA;
    this.varB = varB;

    if ( stage )
    {
        ...
```

Comment: That fixed it! Why can't I assign values to variables already in the function by passing in arguments? Is there a more intuitive way to do this?

Comment: When you wrote `public var varA:uint; public var varB:uint;` you defined two variables in a scope that encapsulates the scope of the constructor `ChildFunction`.  They don't _belong_ to `ChildFunction`'s constructor function but instead belong to each instance of `ChildFunction`.  When you called `childFunction = new ChildFunction( var1, var2 );` you created a new instance of `ChildFunction` called `childFunction` that has its own versions of `varA` and `varB` so they are _in_  the instance `childFunction`, not _in_ the function `ChildFunction`.